# No credentials available while getting credentials from Passkeys

Tags: android, webauthn, credential-manager, passkey

I have successfully created a passkey device in Google and created a credential (screen lock) which can be seen in "Password Manager" in "Manage your Google Account".

I use the following code to create the credential.

```
val createPublicKeyCredentialResponse = CredentialManager
    .create(context)
    .createCredential(
        context = context,
        request = createPublicKeyCredentialRequest,
    )
```

And the result `createPublicKeyCredentialResponse` is like:

```
{
    "rawId": "<rawId>",
    "authenticatorAttachment": "platform",
    "type": "public-key",
    "id": "<id>",
    "response": {
        "clientDataJSON": "<clientDataJSON>",
        "attestationObject": "<attestationObject>",
        "transports": [
            "internal",
            "cable"
        ]
    },
    "clientExtensionResults": {
        "credProps": {
            "rk": false
        }
    }
}
```

However, I cannot get the credential with the following code:

```kotlin
val getCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest(requestChallengeResponse)
val getCredentialResponse = CredentialManager
    .create(context)
    .getCredential(context, getCredentialRequest)
```

And `getCredentialRequest` is like:

```json
{
    "publicKey": {
        "rpId": "<rpId>",
        "challenge": "<challenge>",
        "timeout": 60000,
        "userVerification": "required",
        "allowCredentials": [
            {
                "id": "<id>",
                "type": "public-key"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I catch the exception `GetCredentialException` when calling `getCredential(context, getCredentialRequest)`:

```
androidx.credentials.exceptions.NoCredentialException: No credentials available
    at androidx.credentials.CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.convertToJetpackGetException$credentials_release(CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.kt:276)
    at androidx.credentials.CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl$onGetCredential$outcome$2.onError(CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.kt:152)
    at androidx.credentials.CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl$onGetCredential$outcome$2.onError(CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.kt:143)
    at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport.lambda$onError$2(CredentialManager.java:694)
    at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport.$r8$lambda$nlbYav9mLBoE6Yh1vFKCvITF3ks(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at androidx.credentials.CredentialManager$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.execute(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport.onError(CredentialManager.java:693)
    at android.credentials.IGetCredentialCallback$Stub.onTransact(IGetCredentialCallback.java:123)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1344)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1275)
```

I used the way which is similar to [credential manager codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/credential-manager-api-for-android#1). And I also checked the request and response of signin of the sample app. My requests and responses are similar. And, the sample app of codelab works perfectly in emulator and physical device. However, I can successfully create credentials and cannot get credentials.

Comment: "I have successfully created a passkey device in Google" 
What exactly does this mean?

Also, what are you trying to build? Are you trying to offer sign in with passkeys in your Android app?

Comment: 1. "I have successfully created a passkey device in Google" means: In "Manage your Google Account", under "Security", and under "How you sign in to Google", I have enabled passkeys and auto created a device of my phone.

2. Yes I am trying to offer using passkeys to sign in my app.

Comment: I also got this problem. It feels like the credential manager did not save the credentials.

Comment: Any luck in this issue i am also facing the same

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that the credential ID in `allowCredentials` doesn't match the credential ID returned from the create request. Since the IDs are elided above, I can't say if that's true, but note that WebAuthn uses base64url, not standard base64, in case that tripped anything up.

If you've checked that, try setting `allowCredentials` to an empty list to accept any applicable credential.

If there aren't any applicable credentials, ensure that the RP ID that the credential was created for matches the RP ID used when requesting a credential.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answering. I've check the `createPublicKeyCredentialResponse` and `getCredentialRequest`, and pretty sure that the `id` and `rawId` in `createPublicKeyCredentialResponse` is same as the `id` of one inside  `allowCredentials` in `getCredentialRequest`. I also have tried setting allowCredentials to an empty list, but I got the same error.

I also check the `rpId` that are used to create credential and request credential. They are same. And they are same to the origin I used to create and get the credential, and they are also same to the site of my asset links.

Comment: @HolyRock if you completely remove the allowCredentials from json it will work.
but i am still confuse why its not working when passing credid,  I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
androidx.credentials.exceptions.NoCredentialException: No credentials available
```

means that no passkey was found for this logged-in Google user, therefore credentials are not available. In this case, your code should handle registering a new passkey with the `CreatePublicKeyCredentialRequest`  and then you can run the authentication flow successfully.